# Solution of Linear Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble to solve the system $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = A(t)x(t)$ with

$A(t)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\cos ^{2} t\right)} & {e^{t}\left(-1+\frac{1}{4} \cos t \sin t\right)} \\ {e^{-t}\left(1+\frac{1}{4} \cos t \sin t\right)} & {\frac{1}{4}\left(-3+\sin ^{2} t\right)}\end{array}\right)$

I'm in need of a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives
$$
x_1(t) = c_1\exp\left(\frac1{800}e^{-t}(50(3e^tt^2-16t-16)+2(5(5e^t-2)t+6)\sin(2t) +(25e^t-8(5t-2))\cos(2t))\right),
$$
$$
x_2(t) = c_2\exp\left(\frac1{2400} (50t^2 + 6(2e^t(5t+3)-25t)\sin(2t) - 3(8e^t(5t-2)+25)\cos(2t) \right).
$$

Comment: in the lecture note they directely wrote :
$
\operatorname{tr} A(t)=-\frac{1}{4}<0 \quad \text { ,} \quad \operatorname{det} A(t)=\frac{13}{16}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\cos ^{2} t\right) \geq \frac{10}{16}>0
$
and the the solution of  $x^{\prime}(t)=A(t) x(t)$ is $x(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}{e^{t / 2} \cos t} \\ {e^{-t / 2} \sin t}\end{array}\right)$ . So when my calculus start to be more and more complicated I thought that I'm wrong. I didn't find the ${det} A(t)$ either !!